# Firefox extension that writes to its own log file

Tags: firefox-addon

After a whole day figuring out how to write something from my browser to a local text file.. Im thinking of something like for example a Firefox extension that has a log file.

Is there any way that my extension can write to my extension. Means, inside my extension got a log file.

For information I'm developing for Linux platform.

Answer (score 4):

- [General information on dealing with files in Mozilla code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/File_I%2F%2FO)
- [Code you can use for logging](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Labs/JS_Modules#Logging)